# The new login system seems broken when a user wants to change accounts

Tags: support, user-accounts, login

If a user is logged in with one account and logs out, if the user tries to log back in with *another* account, the user can't because the page logs the user back *immediately* with the old account information, before actually selecting an OpenID/OAuth provider.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the use-case here where you have multiple accounts?

Comment: When using one real name, perhaps you want to sometimes ask/answer/be nasty/be nice w/o revealing your life moniker...

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this, is to use Log Out Everywhere -- click log out, then click the Log Out Everywhere button

[image]
<sub>(source: [stackoverflow.com](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/log-out-everywhere-button.png))</sub>

Comment: Ty. I say the self-login script should give a few seconds, just in case the user *does* click on a provider...

Comment: @remus realistically if you must do this, you should use two different browsers, one for each "identity" .. it'll be much easier.